# Magento does not query all active products in category

Tags: magento, frontend, categories, product

I have a Magento installation which worked fine, till now.

- It has 3 storeviews;
- 2 storeviews are already online and work fine
- The third one is in development

In the third store I'm adding products, but after a number it stops showing in the frontend.

- I checked where it went wrong, and it's in the middle of a category
- I checked visibility and all additional options on categories and products

Next I did:

- Duplicating an product which is already visible in the frontend, the duplicate didn't show up

I checked if the theme was broken so I queried the complete root category in list.phtml:
- In the 2 correct stores the count of products visible is the same as the count of products displayed in the backend under category management
- In the third store, category management says there are 137 products while the count in the frontend ends at 93.

I used this to query the complete root category and counted it:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
  $productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
```

It seems that it just stops the query at 93 entries. I disabled and enabled products but it doesn't make any difference to the 30+ products which are not shown for an unknown reason.. I flushed caches and indexes so that isn't the case. Settings for products are exactly the same since I tested it by duplicating.

What else can I try?

----------- EDIT: -------------

To be exact; the complete code I used to get to loop through the products in the root category is the following:

```
$cat_ID = 41
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_ID);
  $productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
  $productCollection
          ->addStoreFilter()
          ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds())
          ->addMinimalPrice()
          ->addFinalPrice()
          ->addTaxPercents()
          ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
          ->addUrlRewrite();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the code you pasted with this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->addCategoryFilter($category)
     ->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
     ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
     ->load();
```

Comment: I think that's not complete enough. It returns this:

 Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/blokhut.nl/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php on line 719

Comment: I edited the question with the original paste of code I used to loop through all products. It worked in the same template for the other storeviews. So the question isn't; how can I query all products, but it is: why does my template query like it should in my first two storeviews and why is the query limited in my third storeview..